# How to inform Windows something is done?

Tags: linux, windows, notifications

My Linux server will upload some files to the Windows server at a random time.

but the Windows server doesn't know when the Linux server had done an upload.

Is there any method to inform Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's worked well for me in the past is to upload files with a `.tmp` suffix, and then have the sender rename them to the correct suffix on successful transfer. The receiver completely ignores `.tmp` files (except maybe for deleting them if they're a couple of days old).

This ensures that files appear to arrive instantaneously and complete.

Windows, Mac, Linux, UNIX? It doesn't matter as long as the client and server both agree on this same approach.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of dealing with this, independently of the operating system on either side, is to upload a marker file to indicate that the upload is complete. The uploading side uploads all its files, then when that’s done, uploads a file with a specific naming convention to indicate that there’s something for the receiving side to process. The receiving side only watches for the marker files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're talking about "informing Windows", I think you're talking about "informing some process/service/job running on Windows" which means not only you could use marker files, or creating a marker file prior to uploading and deleting it after or any combination of these, you could simply send a network message using any network protocols available including TCP/IP, UDP, ICMP or anything like that.